# How to use multiple WHERE in DB::select in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is the original code:

```
$invoice = DB::select('SELECT MAX(CAST(`invoice_number` as UNSIGNED)) as invoice_number FROM `invoices` where company_id = "' . company()->id . '" ');
return $invoice[0]->invoice_number;
```

The above works great, but I want to use it like this:

```
$invoice = DB::select('SELECT MAX(CAST(`invoice_number` as UNSIGNED)) as invoice_number FROM `invoices` where company_id = "' . company()->id . '" where depa_series = "2" ');
return $invoice[0]->invoice_number;
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
to use near ' where depa_series = "2"' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT MAX(CAST(`invoice_number` as UNSIGNED)) as invoice_number FROM `invoices` where company_id = "140", where depa_series = "2" )
```

How to use multiple WHERE clauses in `DB::select`?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query gives a syntax error, because you use `where` twice.

Try to change it to this, by using the `AND` condition:

```
DB::select('SELECT MAX(CAST(`invoice_number` as UNSIGNED)) as invoice_number FROM `invoices` where company_id = "' . company()->id . '" AND depa_series = "2"');
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`selectRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) method

```
$invoice = DB::table('invoices')
            ->selectRaw('MAX(CAST(invoice_number as UNSIGNED)) as invoice_number')
            ->where('company_id', company()->id)
            ->where('depa_series', "2")
            ->get();

return $invoice[0]->invoice_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you should do
$invoice =

> DB::table('invoices')
> ->selectRaw('MAX(CAST(invoice_number as UNSIGNED)) as invoice_number')
> ->where(['company_id', company()->id, 'depa_series', "2"])
> ->get(); return $invoice[0]->invoice_number;

There will no need to using multiple where statements. You can just put all in an array.